# tensorflow lite add custom op

Tags: tensorflow, compilation

I install tensorflow from source code. As I need to add some OPs in tensorflow lite model, I followed the steps of the tensorflow offical instructions. But in the end, I grep my op name from the libtensorflow-lite.a, and nothing was found. When use the model in my c++ demo, the error is "Didn't find custom op for name 'MatmulCalc' with version 1", however the name can be greped out  in libtensorflow_cc.so after compiling. And the model transfering process is ok.

So my question is 
how to add new OP in lite, maybe the official steps is not complete.https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/op

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you shared is for creating custom Op in TensorFlow. If you are trying to add a custom Op in TensorFlow Lite, the guide is available here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/g3doc/custom_operators.md